# Copy failed on heroku when copying target jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku

How can I change the below Dockerfile so It would get to copy the jar from correct folder?!

I have this Dockerfile

```
# Docker multi-stage build

# 1. Building the App with Maven
#FROM maven:3-jdk-11
#FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8

# Just echo so we can see, if everything is there :)
RUN ls -l

RUN mvn install
RUN mvn jar:jar

VOLUME /tmp

RUN ls -l
RUN ls -l target/

# Add Spring Boot app.jar to Container
COPY "target/programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" app.jar

RUN ls /*

# Fire up our Spring Boot app by default
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

locally ok when building with heroku fails on:

```
remote: drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       64 Jun  7 16:47 classes
remote: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       25 Jun  7 16:47 generated-sources
remote: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       30 Jun  7 16:47 generated-test-sources
remote: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       28 Jun  7 16:47 maven-archiver
remote: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       35 Jun  7 16:47 maven-status
remote: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19578555 Jun  7 16:47 programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
remote: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5664 Jun  7 16:47 programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
remote: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      163 Jun  7 16:47 surefire-reports
remote: drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       17 Jun  7 16:47 test-classes
remote: Removing intermediate container 9b42499c36c9
remote:  ---> 7f7adf538801
remote: Step 10/12 : COPY "target/programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" app.jar
remote: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder05459395/target/programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pure-fortress-92268.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pure-fortress-92268.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

So I see the folder to copy from is different on heroku, how can I change the Dockerfile so It would get to copy it from correct folder?! (I tried many things didn't work.)

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Adding the tree structure of the project:

```
$ tree
.
|-- Dockerfile
|-- Dockerfile.org
|-- Dockerfile.server
|-- README.md
|-- heroku.yml
|-- mvnw
|-- mvnw.cmd
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
|   |-- main
|   |   |-- java
|   |   |   `-- com
|   |   |       `-- tomdog
|   |   |           `-- programmingpdfconv
|   |   |               |-- GreetingController.java
|   |   |               `-- ProgrammingpdfconvApplication.java
|   |   `-- resources
|   |       |-- application.properties
|   |       `-- templates
|   |           |-- greeting.html
|   |           `-- index.html
|   `-- test
|       `-- java
|           `-- com
|               `-- tomdog
|                   `-- programmingpdfconv
|                       `-- ProgrammingpdfconvApplicationTests.java
`-- target
    |-- classes
    |   |-- application.properties
    |   |-- com
    |   |   `-- tomdog
    |   |       `-- programmingpdfconv
    |   |           |-- GreetingController.class
    |   |           `-- ProgrammingpdfconvApplication.class
    |   `-- templates
    |       |-- greeting.html
    |       `-- index.html
    |-- generated-sources
    |   `-- annotations
    |-- generated-test-sources
    |   `-- test-annotations
    |-- maven-archiver
    |   `-- pom.properties
    |-- maven-status
    |   `-- maven-compiler-plugin
    |       |-- compile
    |       |   `-- default-compile
    |       |       |-- createdFiles.lst
    |       |       `-- inputFiles.lst
    |       `-- testCompile
    |           `-- default-testCompile
    |               |-- createdFiles.lst
    |               `-- inputFiles.lst
    |-- programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    |-- programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
    |-- surefire-reports
    |   |-- TEST-com.tomdog.programmingpdfconv.ProgrammingpdfconvApplicationTests.xml
    |   `-- com.tomdog.programmingpdfconv.ProgrammingpdfconvApplicationTests.txt
    `-- test-classes
        `-- com
            `-- tomdog
                `-- programmingpdfconv
                    `-- ProgrammingpdfconvApplicationTests.class

36 directories, 31 files
```

Comment: Would you please provide the tree structure of the project directory

Comment: @MustaphaHadid added tree structure to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `COPY` instruction, the `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build, not inside the building container. You cannot use `COPY` to copy data inside the container. It works locally because you already have the `target` directory from previous builds. Try to remove `target` directory and build the image locally, and it should fail this time.

The solution is to simply replace you `COPY` instruction with

```
RUN cp -a target/programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
```

Alternatively, you can reduce the image size significantly if you do it in one step and clean up after that

```
# not sure why you need to `install` the package in the local repository?
RUN mvn install jar:jar \
    && cp -a target/programmingpdfconv-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar \
    && rm -rf target "$HOME/.m2"
```

You should also consider excluding the maven build directory `target` from the docker build context to increase the build performance by adding a `.dockerignore` file to the root directory.